# Is it possible to remove all the packages installed from a specific repository?

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, software-sources

I would like to remove every package that came from the Multiverse repository. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is with `synaptic`

[image: screenshot synaptic]

1. select 'Origin' on the left
2. select the repository you want above (there are two for multiverse)
3. sort by status by clicking on the icon

Now you are able to uninstall the packages by repository.